# ANGULARJS executing ng-click before href in <a>

Tags: html, angularjs

can anyone tell me what to do if I want to first execute ng-click and after that move to another page? now it's just moving to another page and ignoring ng-click

code:

```
            <div ng-repeat='person in ctrl.people'>

                    <a href ng-click="$storage.x = $index+1;  linkClicked($event, $index)">{{person.first_name}}</a>

            </div>
```

controller:

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", ['$http', '$scope', '$state', '$localStorage',  function($http, $scope, $state, $localStorage) {

$scope.linkClicked = function(e, index){
    e.preventDefault();
    $localStorage.$default.x = index+1;
    // do stuff
    $state.go('main');
}
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
        x: 0

    });
```

}]);

Comment: what are you trying to do via ngclick here?

Comment: sorry, just edited my post, so i want to - add id of chosen option to local storage, and after that move to another page where i can use that saved id

Comment: Which router are you using? Not sure how it is currently going anywhere...no `href` shown in `<a>`

Comment: i am using ui.router

Answer (score 0):

You could do the 'move to another page' logic inside of the logic that is called by the ng-click

something like this

`<a ng-click="ctrlName.doThing($index)">doesntmatter</a>`

and in your controller have this code

`$scope.doThing = function(index) {
    $storage.x = index + 1;
    document.getElementById('main').scrollIntoView();
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent default event by passing `$event` into `ng-click` function and use `$state.go()` once you do what is needed

```
<a  ng-click="linkClicked($event, $index)">


$scope.linkClicked = function(e, index){
    e.preventDefault();
     $scope.$storage.x = index+1;
    // do stuff
    $state.go('someStateName');
}
```

Comment: it looks reasonable, but its not changing anything, any idea why?

Comment: Not without some basic troubleshooting. Is function firing? Is stateName valid? do you have  `$stateChangeError` listener?

Comment: function is firing, state is changed, but my logalstorage is not updated

Comment: to be honest I don't think you need to prevent default or use `$state,go()` and all you need to do is fix setting storage based on your storage module docs